# How to skip a line of (raw) input, Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am completing the following [HackerRank challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sets). I am fed the following input:

```
4
2 4 5 9
4
2 4 11 12
```

Let's say though I just want the 2nd and 4th lines of input (and assume all input will look like this). At the moment I'm implementing a hackneyed solution:

```
seta = set()
setb = set()
delete = input()
seta = input().split()
delete = input()
setb = input().split()
```

I don't use `delete` later in the program. Is there a better, more exact and concise way forward?

Comment: How do you know to skip the first and third lines? Is it because they have more than one number in the input, because they're odd line numbers? Do you need to support alternate inputs, or only this specific one?

Comment: @jpmc26 the OP is skipping the first and 3rd line, and the code challenge in link has a section on "Input Format" that explains that the first and third line contain the number of numbers on the following line.

Comment: @jpmc26: because the other line details how many integers are going to be specified on the next line. For some programming languages it is easier to then read those integers on the next line if you know up-front how many there are. In Python, with `str.split()`, it can be skipped.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Sorry. Got in a hurry and confused myself. Fixed my comment for the right line numbers.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That makes sense, but shouldn't that info be in the question instead of requiring reading content on another site?

Comment: @jpmc26: does it matter at all? The question is complete; *how do I skip reading every second line of standard input*?

Comment: Note that you don't _have_ to assign the result of `input()` to anything

Answer (score 1):

Loop over the [`sys.stdin` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.stdin); it is a regular file and supports iteration. You can use an [`itertools.islice()` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to skip every second line:

```
import sys
from itertools import islice

second_lines = islice(sys.stdin, None, None, 2)
seta = set(map(int, next(second_lines).split()))
setb = set(map(int, next(second_lines).split()))
```

Comment: And of course if more then a few lines were needed you could put `set(map(int, next(second_lines).split()))` in a generator so it only needs to be written once and the sets can be gotten from the `next` value of the generator.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern I often find myself using for HackerRank challenges:

```
def read_set() -> set[str]:
    """Read a set of space-delimited strings from STDIN."""
    input()
    return {*input().split()}


print(len(read_set() & read_set()))
```